# Swap the rows of jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I try to swap the datatable rows in jquery when the top and bottom arrows in the datatable.

Follows a sample of my javascript code:

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', '.swapDown', function(event) {
            var _this = $(this),
        ind = table.row(_this.closest("tr")).index();

       var movedData = table.row(_this.closest("tr")).data(),
        otherData = table.row(_this.closest("tr").next()).data();
        console.log(movedData);
        console.log(otherData);
        table.row(_this.closest("tr").next()).data(movedData).draw(false);
        table.row(_this.closest("tr")).data(otherData).draw(false);
        console.log(_this.closest("tr").next());
        console.log(_this.closest("tr"));
    });

        $('#example tbody').on('click', '.swapUp', function(event) {
            var _this = $(this),
                ind = table.row(_this.closest("tr")).index();
        console.log(ind)
      if(ind  > 0){  
        var movedData = table.row(_this.closest("tr")).data(),
          otherData = table.row(_this.closest("tr").prev()).data();
                                           table.row(_this.closest("tr").prev()).data(movedData).draw(false);
          table.row(_this.closest("tr")).data(otherData).draw(false);
       }

    });
});
```

[Here the complete code](http://jsfiddle.net/zqzzyscy/12/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note DataTable now offers this on there non-editor tables now. See https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/simple.html for details.

Custom Swap Tool:

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // get the table and table body
  var $elm = $('#myTable'),
    $bdy = $elm.find('tbody > tr');

  // add the swap controls to table
  $bdy.each(function() {
    $(this).append('<span class="swap"><i class="up"></i><i class="down"></i></span>');
  });

  // initialize the datatable
  var datatable = $elm.DataTable();

  // fix table border
  $($elm.find('thead > tr')[0]).append('<span class="th-border">&nbsp;</span>');

  // swap the row up
  $('span.swap .up').click(function() {
    var previous = this.parentElement.parentElement.previousSibling,
      parent = this.parentElement.parentElement;
    if (previous && previous.nodeName && previous.nodeName === 'TR') {
      var rowIndex1 = parseInt(datatable.row(previous).index()),
        rowIndex2 = parseInt(datatable.row(parent).index()),
        rowData1 = datatable.row(previous).data(),
        rowData2 = datatable.row(parent).data();

      rowData1.counter++;
      rowData2.counter++;

      datatable.row(rowIndex1).data(rowData2).draw;
      datatable.row(rowIndex2).data(rowData1).draw;
    }
  });

  // swap the row down
  $('span.swap .down').click(function() {
    var next = this.parentElement.parentElement.nextSibling,
      parent = this.parentElement.parentElement;
    if (next && next.nodeName && next.nodeName === 'TR') {
      var rowIndex1 = parseInt(datatable.row(parent).index()),
        rowIndex2 = parseInt(datatable.row(next).index()),
        rowData1 = datatable.row(parent).data(),
        rowData2 = datatable.row(next).data();

      rowData1.counter++;
      rowData2.counter++;

      datatable.row(rowIndex1).data(rowData2).draw;
      datatable.row(rowIndex2).data(rowData1).draw;
    }
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.th-border {
  display: table-cell;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
}

.swap {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.swap i.up:before {
  content: '\25b2';
}

.swap i.down:before {
  content: '\25bc';
}
```

Read about [row().index()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().index()) and [row().data()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()) and [draw](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw)

Comment: Is there any possible way to done this using datatables plugin API?